# What is $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, quadratic-forms

How do you find $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x}$? I only know that $\frac{d}{dx} x^T A x = 2A x$ if $A$ is symmetric. I saw the following on some notes but I don't know how I can reach this conclusion:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} = x^T A x\frac{d}{dx}(x^T B x) - x^T B x \frac{d}{dx} x^T A x$$

Comment: Given that $x$ is a vector, for what I understand, what does it means $d/dx$?

Comment: @enzotib That's one of my confusion as well... We never mentioned about $\frac{d}{dx}$ when I was at school, but to my best knowledge, since the expression is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{d}{dx}$ should stands for the gradient $\nabla$

Comment: Every quadratic form $x^T A x$ can be chosen such that $A$ is symmetric. i.e. $ax^2 + by^2 + cxy = ax^2 + by^2 +\frac{1}{2}cxy + \frac{1}{2}cyx$

Comment: This doesn't seem correct, are you sure the formula doesn't say instead something like
$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} = x^T A x\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{x^T B x}) + x^T B x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x^T A x}?
$

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing some terms (e.g. the denominator terms from the "division rule" for matrix calculus)? Note that $\partial_x x^TCx=(C+C^T)x$

Comment: @Demophilus I found the identity here: http://www.facweb.iitkgp.ernet.in/~sudeshna/courses/ML06/lda.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notes do not say that 
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} = x^T A x\frac{d}{dx}(x^T B x) - x^T B x \frac{d}{dx} x^T A x.$$
Instead they say that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} = 0$ implies that $x^T A x\frac{d}{dx}(x^T B x) - x^T B x \frac{d}{dx} x^T A = 0$. This isn't the same thing, if $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} \neq 0$ the right hand side will look very different.

To prove that $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T B x} = 0 \Rightarrow x^T A x\frac{d}{dx}(x^T B x) - x^T B x \frac{d}{dx} x^T A = 0$, note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T Bx} = \frac{1}{x^T Bx} \frac{d}{dx} (x^T A x) + (x^T Ax) \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{x^T Bx} \right),
$$
and $$
\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{1}{x^T Bx} \right) = - \frac{1}{(x^T B x )^2} \frac{d}{dx}(x^T B x).
$$
So filling this in we have

$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{x^T A x}{x^T Bx} = \frac{1}{(x^T Bx)^2} \left[ (x^T B x) \frac{d}{dx} (x^T A x) - (x^T A x) \frac{d}{dx} (x^T B x) \right].
$$
So this confirms the formula in your question does not hold. But what is true is that if one side is zero, the other must be too.

Comment: Welp, that was embarrassing. Thanks!